# Graphviz not working on google colab

Tags: plot, graphviz, google-colaboratory

When I am trying to plot my model's architecture using plot_model() I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_container_nodes'

Here is my code:

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(my_resnet, to_file='model.png')
```

I have got pydot and graphviz installed by using pip and also installed graphviz via apt-get.

On github some answers say that this is introduced in the newer version of Keras but offer no workaround.